# Exercise about vector fields on smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

Let $V$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $[\frac{\partial}{\partial x},V]=V=[V,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}]$, determine $V$.

The first way to look at this is by observing vector fields primarily as functions from $\mathfrak{F}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to $\mathfrak{F}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Obviously, if $D=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, then $[D,V]=0$.
Writing it out this way: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(V(f))-V(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f)=V(f)=V(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(V(f))$$, we can also see that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(V(f))=V(f+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(V(f))=V(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f-f)$$.

Frankly, I don't know what to do with this. Jacobi identity doesn't give me anything new.

The second way to look at this is to observe these equations locally, at some point $p\in M$. Then we'd be able to write $V$ as $V=\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\beta \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ (or at least I hope we can do this?). However, observed locally, given equations become $0=V=0$, which looks like it's incorrect, because it would mean I have more data than I need.

Other idea was to use the fact that we're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that this is a manifold with one chart basically, but this comes down to the previous idea and the result is the same.

I feel like $[D,V]=0$ is significant here, but I don't know what to do with it. Also, it seems that my attempt at observing things locally is completely flawed. Can we even use the fact that partial derivatives constitute a basis of tangent space the way I've used it?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not constants!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If we assume we are observing just $\mathbb{R}^2$ and there is only one chart and it is $(\mathbb{R}^2, Id)$, then $\alpha=V(\pi _x)$ and $\beta=V(\pi _y)$, where $V$ is seen as an element of tangent space. If I understand correctly, once we start observing everything locally, $V$ is a function from $\mathfrak{F}(M)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $V(\pi _x)$ should just be a value of that function at point $\pi _x$? Are alpha and beta real functions on a (subset of a) manifold?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "locally." In this context it should mean "in an open neighborhood of a point," not just "at a point"; if you work at a point you don't have enough information to calculate the Lie derivative. But in this case it's not necessary to work locally; it is true globally that every smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the form $V = \alpha(x, y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \beta(x, y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, by "locally" I mean "in an open neighbourhood of a point" (observing just a single point would be pointless :D). In a general case, when we have a smooth n-manifold $M$ (not necessarily $\mathbb{R}^n$), when $X \in T_p M$, for some point $p\in M$ and when we want to use the fact that partial derivatives form a basis of tangent space, we would still be able to express $X$ as $X=\Sigma_{i=1}^n f_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, where $f_i$ are some smooth functions on $M$, but not as an $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of partial derivatives?

Comment: You say $X \in T_p(M)$ so it's a tangent vector, but then you write an expression for $X$ where the RHS is a vector field. It's important to be clear about the distinction here. It's true in general that if $M$ is a smooth manifold and $X$ a vector field on it, that if we pick local coordinates $x_i$ for some open neighborhood $U$ of a point $p$ then we can write every vector field in local coordinates as $\sum f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ where $f_i$ are smooth functions on $U$.

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure off the top of my head) that it's furthermore true that given $X$ and $p$ it's possible to find an open neighborhood $U$ and local coordinates where the $f_i$ are constant. However, those coordinates will not be helpful to solving your problem, because they won't necessarily have anything to do with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, which are some fixed specific vector fields.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for answering! I think my notation is imprecise. Using something like $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})_p$ instead would probably be better. The material I've read this from has a theorem that states: If $(U,\phi)$ is a chart in $p$ and $x_i=\pi_i \circ\phi$, then every $X \in T_p M$ can be written as  $X=\Sigma_{i=1}^n X(x_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})_p$,  and that's what I wanted to use for this exercise. But I guess the problem is that I can't transition from globally defined vector field to locally defined tangent vectors this way.

Comment: Yes, assuming I've understood what your notation means, that's a true fact about tangent *vectors*. The corresponding fact about vector *fields* is that the coefficients are smooth functions, generally nonconstant.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\del{\partial}$
$\def\ddx{\frac{\del}{\del x}}$
$\def\ddy{\frac{\del}{\del y}}$
Write $V = f\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + g\frac{\partial}{\del y}$. Then for an arbitrary smooth $\phi$ we have
\begin{align*}
[V, \ddx]\phi &= f\phi_{xx} + g\phi_{xy} - \ddx(f\phi_x + g\phi_y) \\
&= - f_x\phi_x - g_x\phi_y,
\end{align*}
so
$$
[V, \ddx] = -f_x\ddx - g_x\ddy.
$$
Similarly,
$$
[\ddy, V] = f_y\ddx + g_y\ddy.
$$
Both are equal to $V$, so we have
$$
-f_x = f_y = f
$$
and
$$
-g_x = g_y = g.
$$
This system of partial differential equations is solved by $f(x, y) = C_1\exp(y-x)$ and $g(x, y) = C_2\exp(y-x)$, so
$$
V = C_1\exp(y-x) \ddx + C_2\exp(y-x)\ddy.
$$

Comment: (the chance of a sign error in this answer is about 80%)

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I have only 2 more questions: 1. This solution assumes we observe given equations locally, right?

Comment: 2. You (and others) have said alpha and beta (f and g in your solution) are functions, not constants. I'm still not sure why that is, considering formal definitions. Here's the way I see it: If we assume we are observing just $\mathbb{R}^2$ and there is only one chart and it is $(\mathbb{R}^2, Id)$, then $\alpha=V(\pi _x)$ and $\beta=V(\pi _y)$, where $V$ is seen as an element of tangent space. If I understand correctly, once we start observing everything locally,$V$ is a function from $\mathfrak{F}(M)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $V(\pi _x)$ should just be a value of that function at point $\pi _x$?

Comment: @blue The definition of a vector field imples that $f$ and $g$ are functions, and not just constant.